# The named parameter 'user' is required, but there's no corresponding argument in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

It seems like my `page1()` requires a user property, i've tried passing  the property and i still get an error `Undefined name 'user'.Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name`

My code

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
   final User user;

const Home({required this.user});

@override
_HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
 }

  class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
 
 late User user;
 late final pages ;

  @override
  void initState() {
  user = widget.user;
  pages = [
   Page1(user:user),
   Page2(user:user),

 ];
 super.initState();
  }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
     body: pages[pageIndex],
     bottomNavigationBar: buildMyNavBar(context),


    )}

    Container buildMyNavBar(BuildContext context) {
    child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    children: [
      IconButton(
        enableFeedback: false,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            pageIndex = 0;
          });
        },
        icon: pageIndex == 0
            ? const Icon(
                Icons.home_filled,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 24,
              )
            : const Icon(
                Icons.home_outlined,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 20,
              ),
      ),
      IconButton(
        enableFeedback: false,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            pageIndex = 1;
          });
        },
        icon: pageIndex == 1
            ? const Icon(
                Icons.widgets_rounded,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 20,
              )
            : const Icon(
                Icons.widgets_outlined,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 20,
              ),
      ),


   }
 }
```

Page1

```
class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
final User user;

 const Page1({required this.user});


 @override
 State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
 }

  class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {

 late User _currentUser;
 @override
  void initState() {
  _currentUser = widget.user;
  super.initState();
 }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
   ..
  
  );}}
```

Page2

```
class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
final User user;

 const Page2({required this.user});


 @override
 State<Page2> createState() => _Page2State();
 }

  class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {

 late User _currentUser;
 @override
  void initState() {
  _currentUser = widget.user;
  super.initState();
 }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
   ..
  
  );}}
```

RegisterPage

```
class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _RegisterPageState createState() => _RegisterPageState();
 }

 class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {
 ..

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
   onTap: () {
    ..
    },
     child: Scaffold(
      ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _isProcessing = true;
                                  });

                                  if 
(_registerFormKey.currentState!
  .validate()) {
  User? user = await FireAuth
                                        
    .registerUsingEmailPassword(
    name: _nameTextController.text,
    email: _emailTextController.text,
    password:                                 
     _passwordTextController.text, );

                                    setState(() {
                                      _isProcessing = false;
                                    });

                                    if (user != null) {
                                      Navigator.of(context)
                                          .pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              Home(user: user),
                                        ),
                                        ModalRoute.withName('/'),
                                      );
                                    }
                                  }
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  'Sign up',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ), )
  }
```

A user is created on sign up and then has to be navigated to the page1, everything else is working fine except the navigation part.

I've add the register page to show the user created that after signup is navigated to `home()` . Now i want to navigate to `page1()` from `home()`

Comment: In home page, i cant figure out which user you are passing. Where is user definition?

Comment: sorry my bad , its page1 not homepage. i've edit. Please take a look

Comment: I still dont get it, also where is navigation part?

Comment: You never create a user. You are passing a variable user in Home to Page1, but there is no such variable

Comment: I've add the register page where a user is created and passed to home . PLease take a look @IvoBeckers

Comment: @aedemirsen i've add a register page , also i'm using the BottomNavigationBar()  that uses the pages array to navigate the pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int pageIndex = 0;
  late User user;
  late final pages ;

  @override
  void initState() {
    user = widget.user;
    pages = [
      Page1(user:user),
    ],
    super.initState();
  }

  
  ...
}
```

I think you should change your code like this : user: widget.user

Comment: i'm getting an error saying  "  The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression"

Comment: I updated the code, try the new one please.

Comment: It still brings " The instance member 'user' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression"

Comment: ok, you should initialize pages field in init function. I updated it again, check it out.

Comment: Sorry bro , i'm having problem  navigating to page2 after adding it on the array of pages. i get an error when i tap on icon with pageindex ==1 which is page 2. The error says " RangeError(index) invalid value : only valid value is 0 :1" .  Please check the codes i've updated

Comment: it seems correct, try rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

This will navigate from Register page to Page 1

```
if (user != null) {
   Navigator.of(context)
       .pushAndRemoveUntil(
           MaterialPageRoute(
               builder: (context) =>
                  Page1(user: user),
           ),
           ModalRoute.withName('/'),
        );
}
```

Also, change this in Page1

```
class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
final User user;

 const Page1({required this.user});

 //this must be State<Page1>
 @override
 State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,but this will work only if i had to navigate directly to page1, but since i'm using a BottomNavigationBar() ihave to pass first on the home then page1